# Spawning docker - the requested resource is in use

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I creates multiple containers remotely in the VM, but sometimes after rebooting the VM it gets this error and only restarting the VM helps. Do you know what this error means and how to solve it?

> Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError,
> response={"message":"hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem
> 21b0a2583de03c0bb0871be6fc19580b74382c2afe697370b13edac0f31379ab: The
> requested resource is in use.\n(extra info:
> {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"21b0a2583de03c0bb0871be6fc19580b74382c2afe697370b13edac0f31379ab","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\21b0a2583de03c0bb0871be6fc19580b74382c2afe697370b13edac0f31379ab","Layers":[{"ID":"6e512ed6-358b-5ade-be48-2ffe0aca7198","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\99f07daca1c1f27cebf6734e629331f2591365fb10f01087af5006daaf08dcfe"},{"ID":"89732e48-50f0-58fc-924e-116de51e7fa8","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\ffeb491d61491478f7db8de90727ec187246889b07289fcf0167cd81f81bc578"},{"ID":"4d107d52-32b1-58ef-8300-0a6e663ffc96","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\1d3356c9b099fb80301e6e2f4f3a47bbc422e7ddb9c496827d45d9c6e04f5fc2"},{"ID":"0b71aac6-7318-5347-a670-992c14d06613","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\def8b69f42a59ecf75bc8f74ab8a89a08378ce9a8c08b23a266e5b3c6a698e5f"},{"ID":"713ec9da-4c17-5a81-b458-3bd4a5f6ed27","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\abe1c469fd4c7650f55042c06cbe401b02c8bd5aedcb7fabd8c8d7e4a42f827f"},{"ID":"099b6b2c-1067-50b3-99bc-ec9d34027c52","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3f6a34abe173f55b59669c859cc160436dc0d1222d9771bd907098e65efd2d60"},{"ID":"98b515ee-aa27-5fd2-bc30-ef80416b0f6f","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\6968b8cb1c76650fd4cb00f6daa20196c48ed3ea859da838b1e983900ceed1cd"},{"ID":"47ef818f-b569-530b-b886-3b94002eb19e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\75114c4fe304656f0ad6be10eebc8e4a44ea193058bf444b536e2ecd8aa1671b"},{"ID":"0e70a491-247c-5574-b86a-24f209823e52","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\0193da6cbfd630787e298c7aa77274cd40ac3b444edbcaacfb725f9365210c36"},{"ID":"c3c2426f-1d1e-59eb-bd25-9fdb6bc2677e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\06552a9e13e92f67a507de20d1e3a68e94a3510e716b7591d731d4637b3b6441"},{"ID":"ff3c665d-3a3b-563e-9c80-1f86fa8e7735","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3d5e3b9c49041934ffa8917fb26401e6844a65ae0609705cecf57c958f0821c6"}],"ProcessorCount":5,"MemoryMaximumInMB":6675,"HostName":"21b0a2583de0","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["b1c4f68a-6037-4335-ad37-64cd6330159d"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\06552a9e13e92f67a507de20d1e3a68e94a3510e716b7591d731d4637b3b6441\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true})"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stupid message but the problem with parameter -memory https://forums.docker.com/t/error-the-requested-resource-is-in-use-only-when-using-memory/95851 I will spawn docker in windows server and I will be able to use parameter isolation which resolves docker bug